# looping a procedure in a data frame in r

Tags: r, loops

I would like to apply a function for specific columns that have a specific pattern (.theta) in the column names in a data frame.

Here is an example   of what I want to do:

```
RC <- c("A", "B") # predefined categories
adjust.score <- 0.9 # cut score

A.theta <- c(0.6,0.7,0.8,0.97,1.0)
B.theta <- c(0.5,0.8,0.92,0.91,1.1)

data <- data.frame("A.theta"=A.theta,"B.theta"=B.theta)
```

Below is the procedure I want to apply for each column that has ".theta" in it.

```
data$A.theta <- ifelse(data$A.theta > adjustSEM, adjustSEM, data$A.theta)
```

So, here I have only two variables (`A.theta, B.theta`) in this example but I have tens of variables. Therefore, I would like to apply this procedure in a loop or something for those variables that have "`.theta`" extension. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Try `data %>% mutate_at(vars(ends_with('theta')), ~ case_when(. > adjustSEM ~ adjustSEM, TRUE ~ .))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may not need a `ifelse` condition here.  It can be done with `pmax`.  With `dplyr`, we can apply the `ifelse` or `case_when` to multiple columns that have a pattern of 'theta' in the column namee

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     mutate_at(vars(ends_with('theta')), ~ pmax(adjustSEM, .))
```

Or using `case_when`

```
data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with('theta')), ~
          case_when(. > adjustSEM ~ adjustSEM, TRUE ~ .))
```

or with `ifelse`

```
data %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with('theta')), ~ ifelse(. > adjustSEM, adjustSEM, .))
```

Here, `.` signifies the value of each of the column

Comment: thanks for your time and explanation. I used the second solution, worked just I expected.